# App blocking access if I don't allow tracking

Tags: ios, applications, privacy

my government's (Hungary) [health app](https://apps.apple.com/it/app/eeszt-lakossagi/id1550970543?l=en) just received an update and now it prevents me to use it unless I authorize the Privacy Tracking of iOS.

Reading on the Apple knowledge base, I found this:

> If you see a request to track your activity, you can tap Allow or Ask App Not to Track. You can still use the full capabilities of the app, regardless of whether you allow the app to track your activity.

Source: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212025

From my understanding, apps are not allowed to limit the app functionalities if the user doesn't allow tracking. (See policies below)

I tried to contact Apple about that but the operator was completely clueless about the whole App Store policies and the way apps' updates get approved by Apple.

I'm now out of options since there's no way for me to access my COVID immunity certificate if I don't allow my government to track me, and considered the [recent news about spywares used by Hungary](https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/2021/07/18/hungary-orban-spyware/) I don't feel safe to allow a gov app to track me.

Is there any way to circumvent this limitation or report the problem to Apple?

**Policies:**

> Can I gate functionality on agreeing to allow tracking, or incentivize users to agree to allow tracking in the app tracking transparency prompt?
>
> No, per the App Store Review Guidelines: 3.2.2 (vi).

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/user-privacy-and-data-use/

> (vi) Apps should allow a user to get what they’ve paid for without performing additional tasks, such as posting on social media, uploading contacts, checking in to the app a certain number of times, etc. Apps should not require users to rate the app, review the app, watch videos, download other apps, tap on advertisements, enable tracking, or take other similar actions in order to access functionality, content, use the app, or receive monetary or other compensation, including but not limited to gift cards and codes.

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#3.2.2

Comment: Just a word on tracking: remember that tracking permission doesn't give them permission to install spyware on the phone. It gives them permission to use the data they already have access to for tracking purposes.

Comment: @EzekielElin It gives the app access to a unique identifier (other wise it's all zeroes). So "data they already have" is aggregate and not very useful if you cannot tie it to a user in particular across different apps. Although the first statement stands, no spyware that way.

Comment: The question sounds weird. The application must already know exactly who you are in order to display YOUR personal certificate. This is far more than any “tracking”. So actually it might be good practice to make users acknowledge the app is processing their personal information.

Comment: You tried to contact Apple and you got an "operator"?  Stuff like that is better done **in writing**.  Honestly, send them a paper letter.  Thing about a paper letter is #1 they are weird as heck (I saw about 1 a year when I worked in the backend of a consumer facing tech company) and #2 they are physically passed around (like both a curio and a hot potato) to the *correct* relevant party.

Comment: @anki Considering a health app already contains PII and the tracker adds the location to this, it's not that farfetched to assume the tracker got infected. [Hungary recently got implicated using NSO software](https://www.euronews.com/2021/07/19/spyware-sold-to-authoritarian-regimes-and-used-on-journalists-and-dissidents-probe-alleges), that's about the highest grade spyware you can get as a government.

Answer (score 19):

The only solution I found, in order to get the European COVID pass on my iPhone, is to download the certificate from the Government Health Portal (EESZT) and then add it to the Apple Wallet thanks to a 3d party web app.

1. Visit https://www.eeszt.gov.hu/hu/nyito-oldal
2. Login into the website with your "ÜGYFÉLKAPU" credentials
3. Click on the top-left banner that reads "Unios digitalis Covid igazolvany" (it's a JPG so it can't be translated by Google Translate)
4. On the new page that it opens, click on the "Oltási igazolvány" radio box
5. On the table below, you will find a list of certificates, one for each vaccine jab you received
6. Click on each of them and click "Igazolvány letöltése" to download them
7. Visit https://covidpass.marvinsextro.de
8. Follow the instructions to upload the certificates and generate an Apple Wallet pass

Following the above procedure you can store your COVID Green Pass on your iPhone without using the government's EESZT app.